# Showing rows in a multiple select

Tags: html, css

When using multiple in a select can you choose how many rows it shows like you can in a textarea?

Right now it shows only 4 Locations as the default when using "multiple" and this select just happens to be a short list. Is there a way to show like 6 or 7 or all Locations instead of just the default 4 rows?

```html
<select name="Location" id="loc" multiple="multiple" required>
 <!---<option selected value="">Select location</option>--->
    <option value="OPERATIONS">Operations</option>
    <option value="CCC">Contact Center</option>
    <option value="QA">QA Department</option>
    <option value="DS">DeSoto</option>
    <option value="PS">Palma Sola</option>
    <option value="LWR">Lakewood Ranch</option>
    <option value="NR">North River</option>
    <option value="SDL">SDL</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want them to be displayed horizontally?

Comment: No i mean right now it shows only 4 Locations and this just happens to be a short list. Is there a way to show like 6 or 7 or all Locations instead of just the default 4. Essentially making the select larger in size I guess

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `size` attribute:

```
 <!-- This will show 10 items of the list -->
 <select multiple size="10">


 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Then yes - increase the size of the `select` box.

[**JSfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/oavdapsu/1/)

e.g.

```
select { 
  height:300px;
}
```

Comment: I was just curious if there was a way to do it without css like the textarea has rows="6"

Comment: This doesn't allow for deciding how many options will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

You could just change the height.

```css
#loc {
  height:140px 
}
```

```html
 <select name="Location" id="loc" multiple="multiple" required>
     <!---<option selected value="">Select location</option>--->
        <option value="OPERATIONS">Operations</option>
        <option value="CCC">Contact Center</option>
        <option value="QA">QA Department</option>
        <option value="DS">DeSoto</option>
        <option value="PS">Palma Sola</option>
        <option value="LWR">Lakewood Ranch</option>
        <option value="NR">North River</option>
        <option value="SDL">SDL</option>
    </select>
```

Edit: Also as gavin said, using just the size=k attribute:

```html
<select size="8" name="Location" id="loc" multiple="multiple" required>
 <!---<option selected value="">Select location</option>--->
    <option value="OPERATIONS">Operations</option>
    <option value="CCC">Contact Center</option>
    <option value="QA">QA Department</option>
    <option value="DS">DeSoto</option>
    <option value="PS">Palma Sola</option>
    <option value="LWR">Lakewood Ranch</option>
    <option value="NR">North River</option>
    <option value="SDL">SDL</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I was just curious if there was a way to do it without css like the textarea has rows="6"

Comment: Oh. Yes, use the `size` attribute. `<select size="6">` as an example.